# Substring of html with jQuery or pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, substring

I'm currently having a problem. I have a div containing html. But if the html inside the div is too long, I want it to be shortened and three dots added in the end. Now with plain text this would be no problem. With html my problem is this. Lets say i have

```
<div>
    Some <a href="someurl">LinkText</a> and a 
    <span class="this-class">special formatting that's also <b>bold</b></span>
</div>
```

Now if i implement this with

```
$(theSelector).html($(theSelector).html().substring(0,50));
```

will lead to something like this (I didn't count the exact length ;))

```
<div>
    Some <a href="someurl">LinkText</a> and a 
    <span class="this-
```

so i will end up with corrupt html. The easy way to solve this would be just to use the text and not the html but i want to keep the formatting. Can anyone think of a way to nicely shorten this but also close all tags again correctly?

Comment: How about using CSS for this kind of task

Comment: Do you want a trailing reticences in your string or do you want that to be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is not to solve this at the HTML/JavaScript level at all. Instead, use CSS's `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` (you may also need `white-space: nowrap`):

```css
.limit {
  width: 20em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit">
    Some <a href="someurl">LinkText</a> and a 
    <span class="this-class">special fomatting that's also <b>bold</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

Sadly it will happily add the ellipsis in the middle of a word (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012777/text-overflow-ellipsis-avoid-word-break)), but your JavaScript would as well, so...

But if for some reason you can't do that and you do actually need to modify the DOM, I would do it by working through the text nodes, not working at an HTML level:

```js
function applyEllipsis(target, chars) {
  var i, child, text;
  // Loop through child nodes, counting off characters from `chars` until we've
  // accounted for them all
  i = 0;
  while (i < target.childNodes.length) {
    child = target.childNodes[i];
    if (chars <= 0) {
      // Remove any remaining nodes
      target.removeChild(child);
    } else {
      switch (child.nodeType) {
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
          // Normalize whitespace
          child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/[\s\r\n]+/g, " ");
          if (child.nodeValue.length >= chars) {
            // We're all done, trim and add the ellipsis
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.substring(0, chars) + "\u2026";
            chars = 0;
          } else {
            // Not done yet, subtract the number we've seen
            chars -= child.nodeValue.length;
          }
          break;
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
          // Recurse
          chars = applyEllipsis(child, chars);
          break;
      }
      
      // Move to next child
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return chars;
}
applyEllipsis(document.querySelector(".limit"), 50);
```

```html
<div class="limit">
    Some <a href="someurl">LinkText</a> and a 
    <span class="this-class">special fomatting that's also <b>bold</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

You may have to tweak that a bit but it should get you going the right way. In particular, it counts a single whitespace character at the beginning of a block display element (e.g., between `<div class="limit">` and `Some`) which won't be displayed as a space by the browser.

Comment: Awesome this is the best

Comment: Thanks... That's exactly what I was looking for. The more you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, using regular expression

```js
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
var html = jQuery("#container").html();
var result = html.replace(regex, "");
console.log(result.substr(0,50));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    Some <a href="someurl">LinkText</a> and a 
    <span class="this-class">special fomatting that's also <b>bold</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah you can also use css

Comment: Now, you [know this is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454), right? ;-)

Comment: Yes! CSS is best way to do this :) go with css